# Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function and let $\textbf{F}$ be a smooth vector field on $\mathbb R^3$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f$ be a $C^2$ function and let $\textbf{F}$ be a smooth vector field on $\mathbb R^3$.

Explain why div$(\nabla f)=0$ is false.

This was a multiple choice question on a past test. Can someone explain why this is false or drop hints? Thank you.

Comment: How does $\mathbf F$ enter in to the question?

Comment: This question does not make any sense.  Any linear function is a counter-example, as is $f(x,y,z) = e^x \sin y$ (among many others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll worry about $\mathbf F$ when I know its role in the question.  Meanwhile, $\text{div} (\nabla f) = \nabla \cdot \nabla f = \nabla^2 f = 0$ when $f$ is a harmonic function, by definition of harmonic function.  Such functions exist; e.g. take the real and imaginary parts of any holomoprhic function $g(z) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ where $z = x + iy \in \Bbb C^2$; this is of course a standard, elementary and universally known fact to anyone who has begun to study complex analysis.  These things being said, most functions *aren't* harmonic (I leave the meaning of "most" here to the intuition; it can be made rigorous), so the statement that $\text{div} (\nabla f) = 0$ is not *generally* true.  It is generally false.  It is easy to find examples of $f$ with $\nabla^2f \ne 0$; just pick a $C^2$ $f$ and evaluate $\nabla^2f$; you'll *probably* find it is nonzero (and again, "probably" comes with the same *caveat* as did "most").  Anyway, look at ${x^2 + y^2}$.  It is not harmonic.  There are many like it in this regard.  So $\text{div} (\nabla f) = 0$ is not true for arbitrary $C^2$ $f$.

What *is* $\mathbf F$?

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I think $\textbf F$ was inserted in the question as a trick. My professor does that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user95087:  What a professor!  Glad I ignored $\mathbf F$!  Guess I got *that* right.  In any event, thanks for the kind words, and thanks for your "acceptance"!